# Не получается изменить значение элемента

Tags: c++, const

Почему код не компилируется?

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

template <typename T>
void modify(T& A) {
    for (auto&& zzz : A)
        for (auto&& qqq : zzz.second)
            qqq.second = 1;
};

int main() {
     std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, std::set<std::pair<std::pair<size_t, size_t>, size_t>>> A;

     modify(A);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Значения элементов `std::set` нельзя менять через итератор. Только удалять или добавлять. Иначе сломалась бы вся сортировка. 
Чтобы нагляднее представить это, считайте, что `std::set` - это `std::map` без `Value`. Нехорошо менять ключи в ассоциативном массиве без его пересортировки.

Comment: А как можно сделать тогда?

Comment: @mia Я не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите. Попробуйте заменить `set<std::pair<A, B>>` на `std::map<A, B>`. Вероятно это то, что нужно.

Comment: Нет, типы те, что нужно, `std::pair<size_t, size_t>` - ключ. Каждому ключу соотвествует множество других ключей вместе со стоимостями. Короче это взвешенный граф списками смежности с вершинами `std::pair<size_t, size_t>`

Comment: Так раз это ключ, то и сделайте `std::map<std::pair<size_t, size_t> /* ключ */, size_t /* значение */>` вместо второго аргумента шаблона в исходном типе